# Because fstore depends on connectivity >=0.4.6+1 which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.10.0 <2.0.0

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

when I run the command "flutter pub get" I get this answer[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhC5K.png)

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow! Can you copy/paste the error in plain text instead of using a screenshot? It's easier to read and copy some part of it. Thanks

Comment: Can you add your pubsec.yml?

Comment: Because fstore depends on connectivity >=0.4.6+1 which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.10.0 <2.0.0 , version solving failed